# WSO2 DAS: SPARK SQL query with UNION producing errors

Tags: mysql, apache-spark-sql, wso2-das

The following query was attempted to be executed when performing batch analytics with WSO2 DAS using Spark SQL. Tables 'First', 'Middle' and 'Third' are required to be combined and written to table 'All_three'.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE All_three 
SELECT SYMBOL, VOLUME FROM First 
UNION 
SELECT SYMBOL, VOLUME FROM Middle 
UNION 
SELECT SYMBOL, VOLUME FROM Third;
```

Following error is displayed on WSO2 DAS when this query is executed:

```
ERROR: [1.79] failure: ``limit'' expected but `union' found INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE X1234_All_three SELECT SYMBOL, VOLUME FROM X1234_First UNION SELECT SYMBOL, VOLUME FROM X1234_Middle UNION SELECT SYMBOL, VOLUME FROM X1234_Third ^
```

Using LIMIT with UNION is not a necessity to the best of my knowledge. Enclosing the SELECT queries in parentheses too was attempted which didn't work. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

Please make sure you had an whitespace in end of each row.

The reason is it is not considering \n as a whitespace like SSMS or other query editors.

So it reads your query without whitespace. 
Hence, it read like SELECT * FROM  FirstUNION not like SELECT * FROM First UNION

My issue was resolved and I hope this helps for you too.

Comment: Yes, I found this out the hard way subsequent to attempting to get results with applying new line character only. However the actual problem was realized to be the absence of brackets and a temporary data element, which could be resolved as @Isuru Wijesinghe has mentioned.

Comment: Okay. That's fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

There exists a problem with the query you mentioned here. Please change the query as below.

**INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE All_three
select * from (
SELECT SYMBOL, VOLUME FROM First
UNION
SELECT SYMBOL, VOLUME FROM Middle
UNION
SELECT SYMBOL, VOLUME FROM Third
) temp;**

Actually what we do here is, wrapping the **union** result into temporary data element called **temp** and select everything from there. Spark-SQL parser only takes single select element in the insert queries, and at the end of a select query it expects a limit (if available). therefore, you need to wrap the subsequent select statements into one select element. Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Yes, this was realized to be the issue with my query. Thanks for the help!